# Reading particular line while reading text file in java

Tags: java

My question is i come up with a situation that i have a text file that contains following data including 15.

15 // first line

produce,3554,broccoli,5.99,1 //second line

i am using the following code to read the text in the file and printing its output.

```
try

{

File f = new File("filename.txt");


Scanner s= new Scanner(f);

s.hasNext();

String no = s.nextLine();
int num = Integer.parseInt(no);

System.out.println(num);// which prints number 15 only

}
```

now i want to read second line  leaving first one which is "produce,3554,broccoli,5.99,1" in another variable and print it as i print 15 without using a loop . Is there any way that i can read second line.

Comment: Why are you calling hasNext() exactly? Especially if you completely ignore what it returns.

Comment: to check the pointer that does it has a line or not because i am text file is not seen to user

Comment: To check that it has a next line, you should use hasNextLine(). And calling the method but doing the same thing whether it returns true or false doesn't check anything. You need an `if` to make a check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String secondLine = s.nextLine();
System.out.println(secondLine);
```

Comment: if there  are undetermined number of line and want to read each of them leaving the first line which i already read it.so is there any other method to  read every line in the text file leaving the first one

Comment: Execute nextLine() once and ignore its result, then use a loop calling hasNextLine() and nextLine() (if hasNextLine() returned true) at each iteration.

Comment: try
{
File f = new File("filename.txt");
Scanner s= new Scanner(f);
s.hasNext();
String no = s.nextLine();
int num = Integer.parseInt(no);
System.out.println(no);


while(s.hasNextLine());
{
String secondLine = s.nextLine();
System.out.println(secondLine);
}
} i am doing this to read other line but the loop is not terminating . it is terminating when i am reading first line too in that loop

Comment: You have a semicolon right after `while(s.hasNextLine())`, making it an infinite loop. Remove that semicolon. Using your IDE's auto-format tool to indent your code would have shown you this problem.